# Backward Euler Method 1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

"Whats the result of one step of Backward Euler Method with h = 0.1 applied on the IVP:

$ y'(t) = 5y(t) + 10  $

$ y(0) = 1 $
"?

So, been trying to understand the Backward Euler Method for a while now and *almost* get it. However, I don't know exactly what to do and would really appreciate to see how someone who knows what they're doing tackle this problem.

Comment: Euler's method is recognizing that $y(0) = 0$ and $y'(0) = 15$. So you can create a tangent line of the solution to get $y(0.1) ≈ 15×0.1 + 0 ≈ 1.5$ and just keep repeating the process. However, this is backwards, so you'd just go to the opposite way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method says to take the slope from the next point, which is the unknown one, which is why this is an implicit method. Fortunately your equation is linear so that solving the implicit step is easy,
$$
y_1=y_0+hf(t_1,y_1)=1+0.1\cdot(5y_1+10)=2+0.5y_1.
$$
This you can now solve for $y_1$.

Comment: I still _almost_ get it. What does **actually** $t_1$ mean and what happens with it when we replace $f(t_1, y_1)$ with $y'$?

Comment: You have $t_0=0$ and $t_1=t_0+h$ and $y_1\approx y(t_1)$. In general, the ODE function may depend explicitly on the time, that's why one writes it into the method description even if the function does not use it.

Comment: Oh okay, I get the solution now but I still don't really get when I can omit $t_1$ or not. Is there a, kind of, general way to explain that?

Comment: If you explicitly say that you only consider autonomous ODE, then you can use functions without $t$.